# Able to SSH into a machine, but cannot transfer files to or from

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have two remote machines that I am attempting to transfer files between and am having issues. One machine (let's call it A, Ubuntu 18.04.5) I have no problems transferring files to and from from both my personal PC as well as other remote machines. The other machine (machine B, Ubuntu 18.04.5) can be SSH'd into no problem, it can then ping machine A and receive a reply. However, when attempting to transfer files to/from machine B from/to machine A (or even my local Windows machine), using the command:

```
scp machineB@1.2.3.4:/path/file /machineApath/
```

I get the error:

```
ssh: connect to host ###.###.###.### port 22: Connection refused
```

I have also tried to use SFTP and have had the same issue. Any thoughts on why I can SSH into this machine but am unable to initiate file transfer? I have administrator privileges on the machine.

Comment: A network diagram, where any firewalls or NAT happens, and whether any of the hosts have firewalls on them might be handy to know.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) the operating systems of both machines, ii) the _exact_ commands used to copy (you can change IPs to `1.2.3.4` and hostnames to `myhost` or `myhost.local` depending, but we need to know if you are using local IPs, external IPs, hostnames, qualified domains etc)

Comment: It would also be very helpful to be very specific about which machine is the server or client for each operation.